# How to automatically merge selected data and re-cluster in Openrefine?

Tags: cluster-computing, openrefine

I have a big data set that I use in a project on bibliometrics. I want to use fingerprint in openrefine to merge similar yet non identical titles. When I am in openrefine, I can only manually "Merge selected and re-cluster" for 5000 total choices. Given my data set, this method is tedious at best.

I there a way to automatise the process as long as there are clusters to be found?

I tried looking up for information online, but not much to be found given my limited knowledge.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OpenRefine is offering you a "Human-in-the-loop" approach for clustering because clustering methods are not foolproof, meaning the methods may produce false positives.

In the dialog window (see the [OpenRefine Documentation on Clustering](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#cluster-and-edit) for an example) there is also a button labeled "Select all" to automatically select all found clusters.

In my experience fingerprinting quickly converges to a state where no more clusters can be found. So for this one project I would expect it to be faster to use the clustering dialog with the "Select all" button instead of finding your way around the API to automate the process.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @b2m!  I'll double check if the "select all and re-cluster" quickly converges but I'm afraid it is not given the data set has 5 000 000 rows. Openrefine finds approx. 600 to 1000 cluster for the first ten times I re-clustered. Unfortunately, the remaining clusters detected by Openrefine is around 50 000...